# Ruby protected constants, or similar implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, private

I would like to implement the following:

```
module A
  class B
  end
  # can call A:B within module
end

# cannot call A:B outside of module (like private constant)
```

I basically want private constants but I would like to be able to call them with namespacing within the module.

It seems to me I need some sort of protected behaviour on the B constant within A, but as far as I am aware, Ruby does not have protected constants.

I am keen to hear ideas on how this can be implemented.

Comment: @SebastianPalma that designates B as a private constant and will not allow the constant to be called with its namespace `A::B`. A private constant can only be called as `B`

Comment: You're right...

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot"? The only thing that literally _cannot_ be accessed outside of its scope is a local variable. Metaprogramming methods let you access private stuff in Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be done but I have no idea why you'd want to do it.

```
module A
  class B
    def greeting
      puts "hi within #{self}"
    end
  end
  puts "constants within A = #{constants}"
  B.new.greeting
  # <more code>
  # lastly...
  const_set(:B, nil)
end
```

displays:

```
constants within A = [:B]
hi within #<A::B:0x00005b2a18ffc538>
warning: already initialized constant A::B
warning: previous definition of B was here
```

Then,

```
A::B.new.greeting
  NoMethodError (undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass)
```

If desired, you can add `'-W'` or `-W0` to the command line to suppress the warning messages.

I understand `ActiveSupport` has a method [Object::remove_constant](https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.1.1/ActiveSupport%2FDependencies:remove_constant) allowing one to replace `const_set(:B, nil)` (or `const_set("B", nil)`) with:

```
Object.public_send(:remove_const, :B)
```

which may be preferable.